# Unity mobile game touch movement not solid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I have kind of a "bug" in my code that I just can't find why its happening and how to fix it  (I'm a beginner in unity and even more in mobile games in unity )

I have player movement from side to side using the touch but the problem is I want the player to move smoothly when sliding the finger from side to side but the code I have also moves the player where you tap and not only when you slide.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you all :)

**My code:**

```
public float playerspeed = 500f;
public float directionalspeed;
void Start()
{
    
}


void Update()
{

    float movehorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(gameObject.transform.position.x + movehorizontal, -1f, 1f), gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z), directionalspeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // -------------------------MOBILE CONTROLS SECTION STARTS HERE ------------------------------------------------
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * playerspeed * Time.deltaTime;



  
    //collects the postion of the finger on the screen
   Vector2 touch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 10f));

    //if there are more then 0 fingers on the screen , move the ball smoothly on the X axis to where the finger is pointing
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(touch.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Update()
{
    //other code
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        //you might want to lower playerSpeed
        if (transform.position.x > touch.x)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        else if (transform.position.x < touch.x)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```